# How to make a Bounded Integer?

Tags: java, integer

For future programs I need to create a bounded integer class, meaning 0-59(usable for time problems).

I cannot make it "wrap around". For example, bounded `int = 54` if I add `10` it should be `4`.

Comment: `t = (t + d) % 60`. Where `t` is current time and `d` is the delta.

Comment: I suggest you look at [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)

Comment: You'll need to write a class, and + and - won't work, you'll have to write `plus` and `minus` methods and use them.  It'll look probably a lot like `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the `modulo %` operator

```
int modulo = 60;
int value = 24;
value = (value + 40) % modulo;
System.out.println(value);        //  4
value = (value + 50000) % modulo;
System.out.println(value);        // 34
```

---

If you need a class, you can do something like :

```
class MyIntegerBounded {
    private int value;
    private int bound;

    public MyIntegerBounded(int value, int bound) {
        this.value = value;
        this.bound = bound;
    }

    int get() {
        return value;
    }

    void increment() {
        add(1);
    }

    void add(int toAdd) {
        value = (value + toAdd) % bound;
    }
}
```

To use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    MyIntegerBounded m = new MyIntegerBounded(24, 60);
    System.out.println(m.get());   // 24
    m.increment();
    System.out.println(m.get());   // 25
    m.add(40);
    System.out.println(m.get());   //  5
}
```