# Make integer stay always between 0 - 100

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm making a command line Tamagotchi in Java.

It has stats like Happiness, Hunger, Intelligence, and Health. All of these stats should always be between 0 - 100.

And what I want to do is that if some activity makes one stat to go over 100, or under 0, just substract the difference till it reaches an acceptable amount.

I was planning to do that with an if, on the setter. But on a similar question it used a throws. And what I want to do, is the user to don't notice a thing, and the program:

1. Stops adding or substracting a value.
2. When it first overflows, substract the difference to return it to normal

Here's an example:

```
    public void setHealth(int health) {
        if (health < 0 || health > 100) {
            //Here I want the code that returns the value to normal, and the other things I said.
        } else {
            this.health = health;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not adding or subtracting. Judging from what you do in your `else` it's actually easier to do `if (health < 0) health = 0; if (health > 100) health = 100; this.health = health;`

Comment: Related: [*How to make a Bounded Integer?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50592310/642706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BE SIMPLE!!!**

You can treat all `<0` numbers as `0`, and all `>100` as `100`.

Leverage [`Math.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,int)) & [`Math.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#min(int,int)).

```java
public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = Math.max(0, Math.min(health, 100));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED** to combine @oleg.cherdnik's idea into a full class

rather than repeat this logic everywhere make a Ranged or Bounded integer class that enforces the behavior you desire.  Your class should have add set, subtract that enforce the value staying in the range.  It is up to you whether you want to throw exceptions and handle them or just proceed normally but I would suggest not throwing exceptions if this is not unexpected behavior..

for bonus points you could templatize or make the min/max a parameter of the constructor instead of magic numbers like i'm doing below

Example:

```
public class BoundedInteger :
{
    private int value_;

    public BoundedInteger(int v) {
        set(v);
    }

    public int get() {
        return value_;
    }

    public int set(int value) {
        value_ = Math.max(0, Math.min(value, 100));
    }

    public void add(int i) {
        value_ += i;
        value_ = Math.min(value_, 100);
    }

    public void subtract(int i) {
        value_ -= i;
        value_ = Math.max(value_, 0);
    }
}
```

now for each attribute of your class you use a `BoundedInteger` instead of an integer and all operations will function as desired. You can keep the code dry and not repeat it for each attribute

Comment: What's with that code? It looks like an unholy mix of Java, C++ and Python

Comment: guilty as charged. i have cleaned it up